# Characterizing the real analytic Eisenstein series

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modular-forms, special-functions, automorphic-forms, maass-forms

Consider the classical real analytic Eisenstein series
$$
E(z,s)=\left(\pi^{-s}\Gamma(s)\frac{1}{2}\right)\sum_{(m,n)\neq(0,0)}\frac{y^s}{|mz+n|^{2s}},
$$
where $z=x+iy$. We think of $E(z,s)$ as a function on $(z,s)\in\mathfrak{h}\times\mathbf{C}$. The function $E(z,s)$ satisfies the following properties

(1) For a fixed $z\in\mathfrak{h}$, $s\mapsto E(z,s)$ is holomorphic except with poles of order $1$ at $s=1$ and $s=0$ with residues $1/2$ and $-1/2$ respectively (the knowledge of one residue implies the knowledge of the other from the functional equation in $s$, see below).

(2) $E(z,s)$ is $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-invariant in $z$

(3) $\Delta_h E(z,s)=s(1-s)E(z,s)$ where $\Delta_h$ is the hyperbolic Laplacian.

(4) $E(z,s)=E(z,1-s)$

(5) For a fixed $s\in\mathbf{C}\backslash\{\frac{1}{2}\}$, we have $E(z,s)=O(y^{\sigma})$ as $y\rightarrow \infty$ where $\sigma=\max(\Re(s),1-\Re(s))$.

**Q1** Do the properties (1), (2), (3), (4) and (5) characterize $E(z,s)$ ?

**Q2** Is there some redundancy among properties (1), (2), (3), (4) and (5)?

**Q3** What is a good way to characterize what $E(z,s)$ is ? (I guess that representation theorists should have something nice to say for Q3)

**added** Note that $E(z,\frac{1}{2})$ is not square integrable. Indeed,
looking at the constant term of the Fourier series in $z$ of $E(z,1/2)$ we find
that $E(z,1/2)\sim Cte\cdot\log(y)\sqrt{y}$. So if one integrates in the usual fundamental domain $\mathcal{D}_{T}$ of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, up to height $T$, with respect to the Poincare volume, we find that 
$$
\int_{\mathcal{D}_T}|E(z,1/2)|^2\frac{dxdy}{y^2}\sim \int_{1}^{T} \frac{\log(y)^{2}dy}{y}\sim \frac{1}{3}\log(T)^3. 
$$ 
So as $T\rightarrow \infty$ the integral diverges. Note though that it is
"almost" square integrable in the sense that it diverges extremely slowly.

Comment: Your (4) and (5) are not correct. To fix them, you should modify your definition of $E(z,s)$ by including the factor $\pi^{-s}\Gamma(s)$ in front of the $(m,n)$-sum. See for example Theorem 1.6.1 in Bump: Automorphic forms and representations, and note that $E(z,s)$ there denotes the Eisenstein series with the extra factors included (Bump also has a factor of $1/2$).

Comment: But, $\Delta(E(z,s)+c)=s(1-s)E(z,s)\neq s(1-s)(E(z,s)+c)$

Comment: From the spectral decomposition $$L^2(\Gamma\backslash G)=L^2_{cusp}\oplus \mathbb{C}\oplus L_{cont}^2,$$
Any function satisfying (2),(3) and (5) should be in the continuous spectrum. Therefore it can be described by the given Eisenstein series (as it has only one cusp at $\infty$. (2), (3) and (5) imply (1) and (4) with @GHfromMO's correction.

Comment: @Kunnysan: You have to be careful. Eisenstein series do not lie in the $L^2$-space, not even those which contribute to the spectral decomposition: $E(z,s)$ with $\Re(s)=1/2$.

Comment: Dear GH, thanks for the comment you are perfectly. I'll add the Euler factor with the factor $1/2$ so that I at least get the right residues!

Comment: Dear Kunnysan, thanks for pointing out the inconsistancy with the functional equation and the shift with the constant!

Comment: $E(z,1/2)$ is rather special, and its constant term is proportional to $\sqrt{y}\log y$. See the last display in Chapter 3 of Iwaniec: Spectral methods of automorphic forms.

Comment: Dear Gunter Harder, I know what is wrong. In the formula appearing in the display if it is $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}E(z,s)$ and therefore this is why you pick up a $\log(y)$. So I think that what I wrote is correct.

Comment: What you wrote is not correct, and what I wrote was not correct either. The constant term of your $E(z,s)$ is a function $a_0(y,s)$ such that $y^2a_0''(y,s)+s(1-s)a_0(y,s)=0$, where derivation is with respect to $y$. For $s\neq 1/2$ this yields that $a_0(y,s)=c_1y^s+c_2y^{1-s}$, while for $s=1/2$ this yields that $a_0(y,1/2)=c_1\sqrt{y}\log y+c_2\sqrt{y}$. The constants $c_{1,2}$ can be extracted from (6.12) in Bump: Automorphic forms and representations. In particular, for $s=1/2$ we get that the constant term of your $E(z,1/2)$ equals
$a_0(y,1/2)=\sqrt{y}\log y+(\gamma-\log(4\pi))\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: I meant (6.12) in Section 1.6 of Bump's book.

Comment: Dear GH, yes you are right. Sorry for not having understood the point of your comment. So as you wrote, one may write down the appropriate second order linear differential equation and then find its general solution. Another way to see it is to notice that at $s=1/2$ there is a cancellation of the poles of $\zeta(2s)$ and $\zeta(2-2s)$ so that the next leading term turns out to be precisely $\log(y)\sqrt{y}$. Thanks for being persistant!

Comment: I am glad we sorted this out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $Re(s)>1$, the function $E(z,s)$ is smooth on $\mathbb{H}$ and satisfies $(2)$, $(3)$ and
$$
(*) \ E(z,s)-\xi(2s) \cdot y^s=O(y^{1-s}) \ \text { as } y \rightarrow +\infty.
$$
(Here $\xi(s)=\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)$ is the completed Riemann zeta function.) One can prove this by computing the Fourier expansion of $E(z,s)$. These properties characterize $E(z,s)$ since the difference of any two functions satisfying them is square-integrable on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathbb{H}$ (think of the usual fundamental domain) and every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $\Delta$ in $L^2(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathbb{H})$ is $\lambda \geq 0$.

Together with having meromorphic continuation to $s \in \mathbb{C}$ for fixed $z$, this characterises $E(z,s)$.

(Of course, this sort of characterisation of $E(z,s)$ is well-known: see e.g. Lemma 2.5.1 in these [notes](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/mueller/skripte/specauto.pdf) or Lemma 1 in [here](http://www.math.huji.ac.il/~erezla/papers/EisenCol.pdf).)

Comment: Dear Luis, this is a nice characterization. Of course specifying partly what the constant term of the Fourier series is, is not as much conceptual as what I was hoping at first, but may be one cannot do better than that.

Comment: Dear Hugo, I am a bit confused since I did not mention the constant term, just a growth estimate. If you can be a bit more precise about what you would consider more conceptual, then I'll try to think about it!

Comment: Well, by subtracting $\xi(2s)$ to $E(z,s)$ combined with some growth estimate "seems to be close" to saying that $\xi(2s)y^s$ is part of the constant term of the Fourier series $E(z,s)$. For example, if $s=3/4$ it says that $E(z,s)$ behaves asymptotically exactly like $\xi(3/2)\cdot y^{3/4}$.

Comment: I see. But any function satisfying (2) and (3) has a constant term which will be of the form $Ay^s + B y^{1-s}$ (by invariance of the Laplacian under translations). For $Re(s)>1$, you can't have $A=0$ for the reasons given in my answer. So you are just rescaling to $A=\xi(2s)$.

Comment: Why should $A= A(s)$ be divisible by $\xi(2s)$ though?

Comment: Well, often the normalisation used gives $A(s)=1$. In any case, one always has $B(s)/A(s)=\xi(2-2s)/\xi(2s)$; see e.g. Bump's book. So at least taking $A(s)=\xi(2s)$ 'clears some denominators', and is necessary if you want to avoid having poles of the Eisenstein series at zeros of $\xi(2s)$.

Comment: My point was just that if you assume (1)-(5) of the OP's question, there is no a priori reason that $A=A(s)$ and $B=B(s)$ should have a relation to the zeta function.  All one knows is $A(s) = B(1-s)$.

Comment: I agree it is not obvious a priori. But my answer explains that any function $F(z,s)$ satisfying just (2), (3) and (5) (even a weaker version of (5) just asking for moderate growth) will satisfy $B(s)/A(s)=\xi(2-2s)/\xi(2s)$ when $Re(s)>1$, since for fixed $s$ in that range it will be a multiple of $E(z,s)$. So in fact one knows a lot more that $A(s)=B(1-s)$.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at now.  Suppose $F(z,s)$ satisfies (2),(3), (5), then it has a Fourier expansion with constant term $A(s) y^s + B(s) y^{1-s}$ (e.g. see Thm 3.1 of Iwaniec's spectral methods book).  Then $\xi(2s) F(z,s) -A(s) E(z,s)$ is $L^2$ for $\text{Re}(s) > 1$ but this means it vanishes at such an $s$.  By meromorphic continuation, it vanishes everywhere.

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 4):

The properties (1)-(5) do not characterize $E(z,s)$.  The issue is that there's no enough control on it as a function of $s$.  For an example, let $$F(z,s) = e^{s(1-s)} E(z,s).$$
Then $F(z,s)$ satisfies properties (1)-(5).

Comment: Thanks Matt, this is good observation! Probably, one should put some explicit restrictions on the constant $C(s)$ which appears implicitly in the big O notation of property (5).

Comment: Do you have any precise idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the best way to fix it...